# face some problems about RuntimeWarning when import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex7sB.png)

when I import numpy in my python shell, many errors came, which were all timeerror about numpy, saying divide by zero...

Comment: It seems a conflict between lib versions. I suggest you create a virtual environment with a clean python install, and install only the libraries you need. Instructions, e.g. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Also I've seen multiple times that the latest numpy version has problems with compatibility on windows 10. Maybe check that?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried lowering the version of numpy, and it didn't work. But it's a good idea to have a try on venv.

Comment: What happens if you import numpy separately (`import numpy`) rather than via `import cv2`? and since you use python3.9 also try it with an environment where you have an older python

Comment: Import numpy separately has the same warning, and I think the problem maybe lay with the version of python just like what you have said and I will try it out when I'm free. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to install numpy in a environment of python3.8 just now, and it didn't work, there is still runtimewarning. QAQ